# Video playback permissions/path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, permissions, html5-video

How can I play a video using the `<video>` tag from a CodeIgniter application?

```
<video controls = "true" autoplay style="width:100%">
    <source type ="video/mp4" src="<?=base_url("/assets/media/12/upper.mp4")?>">
</video>
```

Full path of video:

```
  var/www/html/project_name/www/assets/media
```

Apache gives me a forbidden, despite css/js serving from this directory with no issues. I've set the `.htaccess` in the `www` directory to `allow all` temporarily, and the issues persists.

Here is the exact entry from `error_log`(httpd):

```
Directory index forbidden by Options directive:     
/var/www/html/records_v2/www/assets/media/12/upper.mp4/, referer:   
  https://dev.site.com/controller/method
```

Here is some (relevant?) information from my `vhost` :

```
                    RewriteEngine On
                    RewriteBase /
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
                    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
                    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
                    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]


                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride none
                    Order deny,allow
                    deny from all
                    allow from xx.xx.xx.xx #my IP here
```

**UPDATE**
After a few days and no luck with this, I've decided to try to get the video to play using a method to read the video data like so:

```
 public function kb_video($article_id, $video_filename)
{
    $path = $this->config->item('media_upload');
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    readfile($path.'/'.$article_id.'/'.$video_filename);
    exit(); 
}
```

And pass the the src attribute like a typical codeigniter URL:

```
(http://site/controller/kb_video/12/filename).
```

This fails without error. I'm not entirely sure, but a `vardump` of `readfile` gives me an `int(0)`.

Any help with EITHER METHOD!!

Comment: CodeIgniter has absolutely nothing to do with the HTML `video` tag or your server permissions.

Comment: My environment has everything to do with my issue.

Comment: CodeIgniter is your framework.

Comment: I understand codeigniter is a framework..running on a server...with permissions.

Comment: What happens when you try accessing the MP4 file directly via browser URL?

Comment: "Apache gives me a forbidden, despite css/js serving from this directory with no issues. I've set the `.htaccess` in the `www` directory to `allow al` temporarily, and the issues persists."

Comment: When you inspect the HTML in the browser, is the `video` tag and its `src` attribute rendered properly?

Comment: Can you show a part of generated HTML, where there's video tag? I suspect incorrect path to video source.

Comment: `<video controls="true" autoplay="" style="width:100%">
        <source type="video/mp4" src="https://dev.dev.com/assets/media/12/upper.mp4">
    </video>`

Comment: @ Vaviloff You are correct. What I thought was the file name was actually a freaking directory.